# D3 fisheye.js plugin on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, fisheye

I've created a simple div map in which I put a map created with a leaflet.js lib as follows:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
center: [51.505, -0.09],
zoom: 13});
```

Then I tried to use the [d3 fisheye plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye) to implement the distortion but I don't have results. Is it possible to use this plugin on leaflet map? 
I tried the following code but probably the problem is that I don't use the object with x,y,z attributes returned by the called function.

```
var coordinates = [0, 0];
var svg = d3.select("#map");
svg.on("mousemove", function () {
    var latlng = new Array();
    coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
    var point = L.point(coordinate[0],coordinate[1]);
    var d = map.layerPointToLatLng(point);
    latlng[0] = d.lat;
    latlng[1] = d.lng;
    fisheye.focus(latlng);
});
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473547/d3-js-fisheye-distortion-on-map) may help.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer... I had already seen that example, in fact i want to obtain the same thing but using a simple geographic map.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you checked if that plugin can distort raster images? It looks like it works only on SVG?

Comment: Hi @ghybs thanks.... I think that the the problem is this, because with the element built with D3 on the map the plugin works fine... Do you know something that can help me to obtain the same result on Leaflet's map? Thanks

Comment: Maybe have a try with Mapbox Studio, I think it renders SVG tiles?

Comment: @ghybs I don't know Mapbox Studio but I have seen that is a software.. my problem is that I have a Leaflet map that is built using a set of tiles, and an example about what I want to obtain can be: I put some node (circle) on map that represent a geografic point on the map using D3, when click on this I want to expand my node to show its structure (i.e graph) and I would to obtain also a distortion of the map so that the expanded node not cover more space on the map. The effect is [this](bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/#chart2) for example. Thanks for your support and I'm sorry if I'm repetitive.

Comment: I think Mapbox Studio would produce vector tiles for you, if I am not mistaken. But from what I understand of what you would like to do, you might be interested in more simple workarounds, like zooming in on click, and possibly in [Leaflet.Deflate plugin](https://github.com/oliverroick/Leaflet.Deflate)

Comment: Again thanks @ghybs, i will see that plugin if it can be useful for me, otherwise i will change the approach beacause I don't find a solution.. A little question, do you know if it's possible to transform the tiles(i.e. .png tiles) in svg?..